# Recommendation for a HTTP parsing library in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, http

I am looking for HTTP parsing library for C/C++.
I have looked curl library, but it seems it is a http client library. 
I am looking for a library which parses HTTP header (e.g. a way to
get the query string, get cookie, get request url, get Post Data)?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you writing a webserver or a plugin or cgi program? i.e. are you really going to receive raw HTTP or 'cooked' headers?

Comment: Raw HTTP headers. I need to pass what I read from a socket and parse the http header files.

Comment: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out [libebb](http://tinyclouds.org/libebb/), it has a [parser](http://github.com/ry/libebb/blob/master/ebb_request_parser.rl) generated with [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/) using the easy yet powerful [PEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) (it's based on Zed Shaw's mongrel parser)

> libebb is a lightweight HTTP server library for C.  It lays the
>   foundation for writing a web server  by providing the socket juggling
>   and request parsing.  By implementing the HTTP/1.1 grammar provided 
>   in RFC2612, libebb understands most most valid HTTP/1.1  connections
>   (persistent, pipelined, and  chunked requests included) and rejects
>   invalid or  malicious requests. libebb supports SSL over HTTP.

Also check [this speedy parser](https://github.com/joyent/http-parser)

Comment: http parser moved here. [https://github.com/joyent/http-parser](https://github.com/joyent/http-parser)

Comment: libebb source code is here -> https://github.com/taf2/libebb/

Comment: Wish there would be a good fast hand written insitu parser for HTTP.

Comment: @Lothar isn't http-parser just that?

Comment: Yes, http-parser is what i found.

Answer (score 15):

About 6 months ago, I was looking for the same exact thing. Then I found this page:
[HTTP Made Really Really Easy](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/)
and I just wrote my own... Works great, surprisingly simple to implement...

Comment: Simple, if you don't care about getting all the corner cases right.  Multi-line status codes, escape characters, international strings.

Comment: True enough. Didn't matter for my use...

Comment: it's been six years since this comment was made. Now, i am looking for http parser in c for my embedded system. I am tight on system resources. @dicroce how were your experience with your own http parser. Should i write my own or use someone's else.

Comment: My experience was very good. We are still using that code in numerous products. You have a lot more options today... if I was doing that work today, I would definitely take a look first at what is available.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to have a look to [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/latest/index.html), which is based on [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/libs/asio).